# Is the set of discontinuities of a distribution function on $\mathbb{R}^n$($n \geq 2$) bound to be countble?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

By distribution function I mean function satisfying the following conditions:

- $\Delta_{a1,b1}\cdots\Delta_{a_n,b_n}F(x_1,\cdots,x_n) \geq 0$, where $\Delta_{a_i,b_i}$ is difference operator with $b_i \geq a_i$.
- $F$ is *right continuous*, i.e., for any sequence $(x^{(k)}_1, x^{(k)}_2,\cdots, x^{(k)}_n) \rightarrow (x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_n)$, where $x^{(k)}_i \geq x_i$ for $ 1 \leq i \leq n$ and $k \in \mathbb{N}$, $F(x^{(k)}_1, x^{(k)}_2,\cdots, x^{(k)}_n) \rightarrow F(x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_n)$.

It is well known that when $n=1$, $F$ is increasing on $\mathbb{R}$ and the set of its discontinuities is countable. My question is that do we have the same conclusion for $n \geq 2$? I doubt not, as for $n = 1$, we have for such $F$ that both $F(x+)$ and $F(x-)$ exist, which plays a key role in the proof, while in $\mathbb{R}^n, n \geq 2$, the convergence of a sequence to a point can be from "infinitely many" different directions, so $F$ does not have analogous property. But I cannot give a counterexample. Could you give me some hints? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Take the product of two delta measures $\delta(x)\delta(y)$. The resulting distribution function is discontinuous along two half lines.

Comment: Pretty clear, thank you!